# Flatview returns only blank lines

Tags: json, react-native

I'm trying to connect a react-native program with some data from our SQL Server.  Here is the Json string that our link returns:

```
[{"Item_ID":2,"first_name":"steve","last_name":"jones","phone":"510-712-1822","email":"sjones@waltersandwolf.com","company":"Glass"},{"Item_ID":4,"first_name":"Tina","last_name":"Wills","phone":"510-222-7788","email":"twills@waltersandwolf.com","company":"Glass","notes":"","json":"{fname: \"Tina\", lname: \"Wills\", phone: \"510-222-7788\", email: \"twills@waltersandwolf.com\", company: \"Glass\", project: \"Portal\"}"},{"Item_ID":5,"first_name":"Sleepy","last_name":"owl","phone":"555-555-5555","email":"owl@forest.com","company":"Forest","notes":"whoooooo","json":"{first_name:sleepy,last_name:owl, phone:55555555,company:Forest, email:     owl, notes:whoooo}"}]
```

Using this code snippet I've found on the web, I'm trying to just get this to show up in a flatview but it is blank:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, View, Alert, ActivityIndicator, Platform} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component  {

  constructor(props)
   {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://functions-ww.azurewebsites.net/api/SteveListJSON')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         dataSource: responseJson
       }, function() {
         // In this block you can do something with new state.
       });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
     });
 }

FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#607D8B",
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  GetFlatListItem (company) {

  Alert.alert(company);

  }


  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
   }

    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

   <FlatList

      data={ this.state.dataSource }
      ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.FlatListItemStyle} onPress={this.GetFlatListItem.bind(this, item.company)} > {item.company} </Text>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
     />


</View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{

justifyContent: 'center',
flex:1,
margin: 10,
paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 0,

},

FlatListItemStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },

});
```

I would appreciate any help you could provide.  I'm new at this so it may be something simple I'm missing...

Comment: Try to add `dataSource` to `this.state = {
    isLoading: true
    }` in `constructor `

Answer (score 0):

Url is returning response as string and the datasource you need is an object so before setting the state of datasource change it to an object.
Add this:--

```
this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         dataSource: JSON.parse(responseJson)
       }
```